# Mongodb recover lost documents

Tags: mongodb, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes

I was trying to create unique index on my collection. I ran

```
db.responses.ensureIndex({'meta.instanceId': 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

since `meta.instanceId` key was not present in the documents, mongodb deleted all the documents in the collection except for one.

How can I recover my deleted documents?

Comment: Another good reason why ["dropDups"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#index-build-enhancements) is now deprecated and hopefully soon to be gone. This is what backups and lagging replica set members are for. Without them your data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a replica set? If this is true, you can find the deleted documents in the `oplog` which keeps tracks of the operations that have taken place in your replica.
You can query the `oplog` by:

```
use local;
db.oplog.rs.find({'your query'});
```

The oplog is not any kind of backup or something, it is internal and it could change unexpectedly.

If you are not on a replica set I'm afraid your docs are gone.